# Using QuickCheck properties with coverage inside a monadic context

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I'm trying to write a QuickCheck property that uses `cover` to make sure that the test data covers certain cases in combination with the fact that the test involves an IO action.

The problem essentially boils down to the following:

```hs
prop = do
  res <- exampleIOAction
  cover 40.0 (even res) "res is even" $ res > 0

-- some IO action that returns an Int, the actual implementation doesn't matter
exampleIOAction :: IO Int
exampleIOAction = undefined
```

The interesting detail is that I want to `cover` based on the results of an IO action. However, the code fails to compile because `Couldn't match expected type ‘IO b’ with actual type ‘Property’`.

I tried using `Test.QuickCheck.Monadic` but I wasn't able to get it to work. Is there any way to do that with QuickCheck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Test.QuickCheck.Monadic

prop :: Property
prop = monadicIO $ do
  res <- run exampleIOAction
  stop (cover 40.0 (even res) "res is even" $ res > 0)
```